# images in my Grid View disappear as I scroll

Tags: android, multithreading, gridview, bitmap

I'm using Grid View in order to show images I have stored, but as I scroll down the images disappear in Image View and don't load again.I also use thread for loading images into Image View.
Here is my code(also these codes are in my grid view adapter class) :

```
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.e("sara" , "this part takes time");


            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();


            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gallery_gridsq, parent, false);
            iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            file = new File(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()).getPath());
            new myTask(iv, file).execute();

            return convertView;
        }


        private class myTask extends AsyncTask <Void , Void ,Bitmap> {
            ImageView iv;
            File file;

            public myTask(ImageView iv, File file) {
                this.iv=iv;
                this.file= file;
            }



            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                options.inSampleSize = 8;
                try {
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bmp;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap aVoid) {

                iv.setImageBitmap(aVoid);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of the memory issue that caused me the similar trouble.

Check if your getView is still called when you scroll down with your log: `Log.e("sara" , "this part takes time");`

If that line is called when you scroll down, check the memory from android monitor provided in the android studio.

click `android monitor` at the bottom > `monitors`> and observe if memory reaches the cap depending on the set up (probably 128 or 256MB).

If so you are having issues with memory. The very possible reason is that you are not recycling the list and the memory is stacking. At the peak of memory, the images will not be loaded.

It should be implemented in a way that the images that you already loaded be deleted as you scroll down and load new images.

Also, try using [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for it has a good solution with memory issues and generally better in many fields than bitmapfactory.